# How to Correct android kotlin send JSON malformed

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin

i try to send Json array in volley . but my post sending section malformed. anyone help me ?

Now getting

```
{
Id=1233,
 SelRefids=[{
"Refno":"002",
"H_dt":"2021-04-30T00:00:00"
},{
"Refno":"001","H_dt":"2021-04-30T00:00:00"
}]  }
```

Correct format.

```
{
    "Id": "1233",
    "SelRefids": [{
        "Refno": "002",
        "H_dt": "2021-04-30T00:00:00"
    }, {
        "Refno": "001",
        "H_dt": "2021-04-30T00:00:00"
    }, {
        "Refno": "001",
        "H_dt": "2021-04-30T00:00:00"
    }, {
        "Refno": "003",
        "H_dt": "2021-04-30T00:00:00"
    }]

}
```

Volley Send code sample

```
override fun getParams(): HashMap<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("Id", "1233")
                params.put("SelRefids", payarray.toString())              
                return params
            }
```

Thank you so much for your Help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding quote inside your strings ?

```java
params.put("\"Id\"", "1233")
params.put("\"SelRefids\"", payarray.toString())
```

Comment: hai @shaddo I am change now also error json                                                               
      `    {
 "SelRefids" = [{
  "Refno": "002",
  "H_dt": "2021-04-30T00:00:00"
 }, {
  "Refno": "001",
  "H_dt": "2021-04-30T00:00:00"
 }], "Id" = "12345"
}`